# Linux UDP recvfrom: What do I get at the start of my buffer?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

What do I get at the start of my buffer in case my call to `recvfrom` returns a valid amount of bytes (e.g. `1400`)?

Do I get an `ethhdr`? This code doesn't work for example even though I should be receiving UDP-Packets:

```
void read_packets(struct config *cfg) {

    int64_t read_bytes = recvfrom(cfg->socket_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if(read_bytes == -1) {
        return;
    }

    cfg->stats.amnt_of_packets += 1;
    cfg->stats.amnt_of_bytes += read_bytes;

    struct ethhdr *eth = (struct ethhdr*)(buffer);
    if(ntohs(eth->h_proto) == ETH_P_IP) {
        struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
        if(iph->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP) {
            /* doesn't work */
        }
    }
}
```

`socket_fd` was created as:

```
cfg->socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
```

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I added this information to my original post

Comment: Sockets of type SOCK_DGRAM will get only the UDP payload data.  If you want access to the lower-level networking headers (and in most cases, you don't), you'll need to instantiate a SOCK_RAW socket instead.  (see also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896944/recvfrom-with-raw-sockets-get-just-the-data )

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So this means in my case I get a `struct udphdr`?

Comment: No, in your case you get only whatever UDP payload data the sending program passed in to its `sendto()` call.  No system-defined header data of any kind is exposed to the normal network-program (except when using raw sockets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `recvfrom` on a UDP socket will only return the payload of the UDP packet, i.e. what the sending end passed to `sendto`.  You won't see the ethernet header, IP header, or UDP header as part of this.

You did however pass NULL values for the last two arguments.  These can be used to populate a `struct sockaddr_in` structure which will contain the IP address and UDP port of the sending side.

Also, if you use `recvmsg`, you have the ability to get the values of some fields from the IP header such as the destination IP address (useful if the socket is receiving multicast packets), the TOS/DSCP field, or various IP options that may be set.

Comment: The destination IP address is important even if you aren't dealing with broadcast of multicast packets. Traditional sendto/recvfrom on a socket bound to 0.0.0.0 or :: is fundamentally broken as soon as a server has more than one IP address.