# Need clarification on the return value of recvfrom() when using raw sockets

Tags: sockets, udp, ip, rtp

Does the return value(received byte count) of recvfrom(...) include the ip/udp/rtp header size, when using raw udp sockets?

```js
/*
send("hello world");
.
.
ret = recvfrom(...);


ret == len("hello world")
OR
ret == sizeof(IP header)+sizeof(UDP header)+len("hello world")
*/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recvfrom with Raw Sockets, get just the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896944/recvfrom-with-raw-sockets-get-just-the-data)

Comment: @Kitsu  No,
I need to know if the return value is inclusive of the ip/udp/rtp header size, or is it just the size of data (payload).

Comment: From the link: "The IP header will always be included when receiving on a SOCK_RAW socket". Isn't it the answer?

Comment: @Kitsu I have added some sudo code for more context .

Comment: Read the documentation again. It is the number of bytes *transferred,* i.e. moved into your application buffer. But why are you using raw sockets with a UDP-based protocol?